# C# - only text row will be store in database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

When I type in datagridview textbox next row automatically generated.

How to stop that ?

When I clicked on Insert button empty row also store in database that is why I'm asking how to stop automatically row generate ?

I want only text ROW will be store in database, null or empty row does not store in database ??

```
 string StrQuery;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection string))
{
using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
{
comm.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();
for(int i=0; i< dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++)
{
StrQuery= @"INSERT INTO std VALUES ('"
+ dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["sname"].Value +"', '"
+ dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["class"].Value +"')";
comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Set **AllowUserToAddRows** Property to false

But according to your code you must have to place check in your for look and check the values of cell if those are null or not by using something like this

```
        for(int i=0; i< dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++) 
    { 
if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["sname"]!=null)
{
    StrQuery= @"INSERT INTO std VALUES ('" 
    + string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["sname"].Value) +"', '" 
    + string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["class"].Value) +"')"; 
    comm.CommandText = StrQuery; 
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
    }
```

Because if you stop grid to add rows automatically then you have to do that manually to insert new rows. So the best thing is you must let the grid add news rows. But place the check of null values in your code.

Comment: Set AllowUserToAddRows Property to false

i have done this after that rows will generated ...

i just want to empty row not inserted in database

Comment: use string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(your value)

Comment: Sorry mybad, i didn't know you were working on vs2008, use string.IsNullOrEmpty instead and let me know

Comment: when i typed string dot Isnullorempty is shown in code area ...isnullorwhitespace not shown in codearea

Comment: Follow this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: these 2 error will shown in my code area:
 The best overloaded method match for 'string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)' has some invalid arguments 

Error 2 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: Use this string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["sname"].Value.ToString()). After Value, use .ToString()

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
exception will show :-

Comment: Using the comments to interactively debug is a misuse of the comments section.  Please refrain from doing it.